# "from google.cloud.speech import enums" выдаёт ошибку: "cannot import name 'enums'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

решила поработать с Speech-to-Text Client Libraries. Не получается распаковать google.cloud.speech(через pip установила, но работать не хочет). Пишет ошибку cannot import name 'enums'. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'audio.raw')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US')

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте обновить этот модуль: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`

И использовать в своем коде `speech_v1` вместо `speech`.

Подробнее: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/vision-0.33.0/speech